# Error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, spinner

hi I created one simple xml based spinner application.i got all value in my xml file using sax parser. I have two spinner and one grid view, the 1st spinner display one array list value 2nd spinner display one array list. The same time grid view display some images in bottom. this process working fine. now i wish to create text with images spinner so i used row.xml file in my resource folder and i change my code also but i am getting error. what mistake i made in my code.....

error line:

```
label.setText(hltag_List[position]);
```

Comment: Seriously? You didn't even look up the api...

Comment: error line label.setText(hltag_List[postion]); error:The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see you are using arraylist in constructor

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   ArrayList<String> hltagList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, hltagList);
}
```

whereas accessing its elements via array. just change your line to

```
label.setText(hltag_List.get(position));
```

Change your adapter code to following if, you have an array in datasource:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] hltagList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, hltagList);
        }
```

and keep the line:

```
label.setText(hltag_List[position]);
```

Comment: thanks it's working fine sharma and one more i have sdcard path value in one arraylist that arraylist name is path_List. please see my coding i wish to show that path_List images give me your idea...

Comment: i wish to show that path_List images into my spinner. now i am showing custom images in my drawable folders how to change arr_images[] to path_List sharma....

Comment: ok sharma that problem is solved. my doubt is before i show images with text in spinner. the text is dynamic and images is custom so i am trying to change arr_images[] to path_List the path_List nothing its arraylist i stored sdcard path value as string...how to show that path_List string value to images format in spinner

Comment: Just define a custom adapter, which loads image from web and shows on imageview and set that adater to spinner instead of using SimpleArrayAdapter

Answer (score 4):

If it is a Arraylist , use hltag_List.get(position) .

```
label.setText(hltag_List.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ArrayList.get(int index) to obtain the i-th object in the list.